# List of nums (column) in variable Bash

Tags: bash

I want to create code that creates a variable containing the number of positional arguments as a consecutive list.

For example, if the number of positional arguments (`$#`) is `5` then:

```
var='
1
2
3
4
5'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`seq`](https://ss64.com/bash/seq.html)

```
echo "$#" 
5
var=$(seq 1 $#)
echo "$var"
1
2
3
4
5
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzU5I19BSUVZSUFZQddOwZSrLLHIVkWjOLVQwVBBRVmTC6oAKKz0////xP9J/5M5/6f8TwUA)

Comment: Glad it helped! Please consider [upvoting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) or [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) any answers that might have helped you. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.